# Testsuite junit report

Tags: eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver

i need to create testsuite report in junit. When i run the testsuite it gets executed properly, but when i run build.xml file to create the junit report of the test suite it doesn't get created
    Code :

```
Class first :

public class first extends TestCase{
public static WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public static void testsetup()
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver.exe");
  System.out.println("Before class");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
 }
@Test
public void testlogin()throws Exception
{
    driver.get("URL");
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath");
    login.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
    login.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("pwd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath")).click();
}
@Test
public void testnext()throws Exception
{
    //My code
}
@AfterClass
public static void testafterClass()
{
    driver.close();

}
```

Class second :

```
public class second extends TestCase{
public static WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public static void testsetup()
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver.exe");
  System.out.println("Before class");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
 }
@Test
public void testlogin()throws Exception
{
    driver.get("URL");
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath");
    login.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
    login.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("pwd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath")).click();
}
@Test
public void testnext()throws Exception
{
    //My code
}
@AfterClass
public static void testafterClass()
{
    driver.close();

}
```

TestSuite Code:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({first.class,second.class})
public class AllTests 
{}
```

Build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="Section">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="C:/Users/Downloads/eclipse"/>
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
<path id="Section.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="C:/Users/Downloads/selenium4junit-1.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/jxl-2.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:/Users/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.2/lib/ant-junit.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="AllTests">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.AllTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="first">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.first" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="second.testnext">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.second" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="second.testlogin">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.second" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="second.testsetup">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.second" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="second">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="Projects.second" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="Section.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you show us the build.xml code that you have used?

Comment: I am sure, there is something wrong in build.xml file. But am not sure what is it. Please do let me know